# interstitial ads not repeating

Tags: timer, admob, interstitial

I got stuck showing interstitial ads after an interval. my code displays only once (after 60 seconds). I want to show the interstitial ads in every 60 seconds interval. I know this is not a good idea to implement ads this way but I need this.. my code is below:

```
package com.ronie.admobads;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Banner Ad
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);

// Insert the Ad Unit ID
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);


        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        MainActivity.this.mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }
                }, 60000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

@Abhishek, I tried your way but Interstitial Ads doesn't show. I can see only banner ads. Would you please check if my I am wrong anywhere inside the code?
Full code is below:

```
package com.ronie.admobads;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Banner Ad
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Prepare the Interstitial Ad
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);

// Insert the Ad Unit ID
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);


        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // don't show Ad here
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                createRequest();   //load request whenever ad closed by user
            }
        });

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                else
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                createRequest();
            }
        }, 1,1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

        public void createRequest(){

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        }

    }
```

Comment: you are trying to implement Disallowed interstitial .. if you are able to write code doesn't mean its correct way. Your app will be banned if you do this

Comment: This is against AdMob's TOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule your event in this way :

```
createRequest();

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // don't show Ad here
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                createRequest();   //load request whenever ad closed by user
            }
        });

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    else
                        createRequest();
                }
            }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

And `createRequest` method

```
public void createRequest(){

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

**EDIT**

My mistake, I apologize, thread become dead because of `java.lang.IllegalStateException`, Need to call on the main UI thread.

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                          @Override
                          public void run() {
                              if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
                                  mInterstitialAd.show();
                              else
                                  createRequest();
                          }
                      });
                }
            }, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: I'll check as soon as I free.